# Alternate Solution for Retired Jars

Tags: java, jar, taglib

Anyone can suggest any alternate libraries for the below retired Jakarta libraries:

1. taglibs-datetime.jar
2. taglibs-mailer.jar
3. taglibs-string.jar

Please can anyone help me to find this

Answer (score 1):

1. taglibs-datetime.jar: use the [JSTL date/time tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html) like `fmt:formatDate`
2. taglibs-mailer.jar: I don't know... maybe use a servlet to send your mail?
3. taglibs-string.jar: use the [JSTL string functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html)

Comment: Thanks :) @LarsGendner..will try on this